# If Term Name Exists, Append a Unique ID to Slug

Tags: customization, taxonomy, slug

How would I go about adding a unique ID to a custom taxonomies slug?

We have multiple users who can create their **own** taxonomies.

The problem occurs when two users wish to create a taxonomy of the same name, eg. "Clothing" which results in WordPress presenting the error:

**A term with the name provided already exists with this parent.**

Our thinking is, if it's possible, to append either the term's ID, eg. "Clothing-242" or the user's ID, "Clothing-12" to the slug.

Comment: Are they adding Terms or Taxonomies? It sounds like you're using taxonomies, but WordPress doesn't have a UI for creating those. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: I may be mixing up my terminology... I think I mean categories within a custom taxonomy?

eg. www.domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php? **taxonomy=vendor-category&post_type=product**